# Android navigation drawer prevent reloading of same fragment

Tags: java, android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I created a new android studio project from the navigation drawer template but I have a problem.
I want to make it so that when I am at fragment "Home" and I select "Home" from the navigation drawer, the fragment does not get reloaded. How do I do that?

Comment: You should add more information about the current way you have implemented navigation drawer, because there is a lot of ways to make reloading of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Show the current fragment and hide others from the methods show hide..
Google how to do it. A quick fix.

But the correct way is setting a fragment pager adapter and setting off screen limit or doing changes you want in the adapter.
Also I am not putting more info.. Just there is many more information out there.. Google 
Setup navigation drawer view with fragments pager adapter and you will find many.